Terraform Azurerm Modules with Loop Destroys Resources
I'm struggling with a problem in Terraform and Azurerm Provider.
I have a module, it creates a Service Bus Queue and Subscription to an existing Service Bus Topic and forwards all messages to a the Queue.
I have the Subsciprionts and Queue names in the locals.tf files
  event_topics = [
    {
      topic_name = "account.created.v1"
      queue_name = "account_created_v1"
    },
    {
      topic_name = "account.activated.v1"
      queue_name = "account_activated_v1"
    }
  ]

Then I have a module
module "subscriptions" {
  source = "./modules/subscription"

  for_each = { for idx, obj in local.event_topics : idx => obj }

  topic_name        = each.value.topic_name
  queue_name        = each.value.queue_name
  subscription_name = "message-listener"
  servicebus_id     = var.hub_servicebus_id
}

And the main part of the module:
data "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "sub" {
  name         = var.topic_name
  namespace_id = var.servicebus_id
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_subscription" "sub" {
  name               = var.subscription_name
  topic_id           = data.azurerm_servicebus_topic.sub.id
  forward_to         = azurerm_servicebus_queue.sub_queue.name
  max_delivery_count = 5
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_queue" "sub_queue" {
  name               = var.queue_name
  namespace_id       = var.servicebus_id
  max_delivery_count = 5
}

This all worked well.. until I've come to re-run the terraform and now it seems to be processing the loop in a different order and wanting to delete and re-create subscriptions and queues. I can't let it do this as there are some messages both in dead-letter and normal queues that are waiting to be processed.
Have I done something wrong?

Don't create multiple resources based on an index of an array - if the order changes for some reason resources might be deleted/recreated. Use a map instead.

Moving to a map instead of an index array:
locals.tf
locals {
  event_topics = {
    "account_created" = {
      topic_name = "account.created.v1"
      queue_name = "account_created_v1"
    },
    "account_activated" = {
      topic_name = "account.activated.v1"
      queue_name = "account_activated_v1"
    }
  }
}

main.tf
module "subscriptions" {
  source = "./modules/subscription"

  for_each = local.event_topics

  topic_name        = each.value.topic_name
  queue_name        = each.value.queue_name
  subscription_name = "message-listener"
  servicebus_id     = var.hub_servicebus_id
}

seems to do the trick
